How to bind Alt + hjkl and to arrow keys without messing up alt + tab
I've found this other post here which suggests to do this to bind Alt + hjkl to arrow keys
xmodmap -e "keycode 64 = Mode_switch" # set Alt_l as the "Mode_switch"
xmodmap -e "keycode 43 = h H Left H" # h
xmodmap -e "keycode 44 = j J Down J" # j
xmodmap -e "keycode 45 = k K Up K" # k
xmodmap -e "keycode 46 = l L Right L" # l

however this messes up the functionality of Alt + tab which I would like to keep.
Additionally I'd like to bind alt + n and Alt + m to go to the beginning and end of the line I'm on. How would these things be possible to achieve? Thanks!

You appear to answer your own question in a comment. Not what comments are for. At the bottom of your question is the option to answer own question. Please use that.

Anyone who wants to do this should use input remapper.
KEY_END and KEY_HOME will get you to the end and beginning of the line. I used AT Translated Set 2 keyboard when you get to options.

Seems like overkill just a little.  Using xbindkeys is the more simple approach.
